# Match Non-exhaustive failure

Tags: sml, smlnj

I cannot figure out which case I am missing here,for my functions,can someone help me find which case to consider also so that I do not get the match non-exhaustive error.It is taking time for me to really figure out which part is missing.

```
fun eval_1 (nil,_) = nil
  | eval_1 (_,nil)  = nil 
  |eval_1 ((x::h::xs),(y::t::ys)) = if x = ~1 then (h,t)::eval_1(xs,ys) else(x,y)::eval_1(h::xs,t::ys);

fun eval_2 (nil,_) = nil
  | eval_2 (x,nil) = nil 
  |eval_2 ((x),(y::ys)) = eval_1 (x,y)::eval_2(x,ys);

 fun eval_3 (nil,_) = nil
   | eval_3 ((x::nil),nil) = nil 
   | eval_3 ((x::xs),(ys)) = eval_2(x,ys)::eval_3(xs,ys);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching on `(x:xs, y:ys)` instead of `((x::h::xs),(y::t::ys))` gets rid of the non-exhaustive warning. To make the rest of the code equivalent you can use `hd` and `tl` from `List` to get the head of the tail and the tail of the tail instead of decomposing the list with `x::next::xs`.

```
fun eval_1 (nil,_) = nil
  | eval_1 (_,nil) = nil 
  | eval_1 (x::xs, y::ys) =  if x = ~1 then (hd xs, hd ys)::eval_1(tl xs, tl ys) else (x,y) :: eval_1(xs, ys)

fun eval_2 (nil,_) = nil
  | eval_2 (x,nil) = nil 
  | eval_2 ((x),(y::ys)) = eval_1 (x,y)::eval_2(x,ys);

fun eval_3 (nil,_) = nil
  | eval_3 ((x::nil),nil) = nil 
  | eval_3 ((x::xs),(ys)) = eval_2(x,ys)::eval_3(xs,ys);
```

Sample run:

```
> val eval_1 = fn : int list * 'a list -> (int * 'a) list
val eval_2 = fn : int list * 'a list list -> (int * 'a) list list
val eval_3 = fn : int list list * 'a list list -> (int * 'a) list list list
val it = () : unit
> eval_1([1,2,3], [4,5,6]);
val it = [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)] : (int * int) list
```